# Can send batch insert but not update queries to DB

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I can successfully send batch insert requests to the DB, but not updates. I have tried different approaches, but nothing seems to issue the batch updates.

I could not find a solution for this issue. Some examples I've tried (not all):

- [nhibernate : executing updates in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471952/nhibernate-executing-updates-in-batches)
- [NHibernate bulk insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560584/nhibernate-bulk-insert-or-update)
- [NHibernate batch insert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224583/nhibernate-batch-insert-not-working)

***Important. I must not use stateless sessions.**

Here is a unit test I use to test this case:

```
[Test]
public void Test_BatchUpdateTest()
{
    // Arrange
    const int batchSize = 2;

    var dto1Oid = Guid.Empty;
    var dto2Oid = Guid.Empty;

    // Generates a transaction, executes the content, and commit it afterwards. 
    // Batch inserts are correct, both are sent with no extra roundtrips to DB.
    businessObject.Transact(() => {
        var dto1 = new DtoType {ArchivingDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)};
        var dto2 = new DtoType {ArchivingDate = DateTime.Now};
        businessObject.Save(dto1); // Calls Session.SaveOrUpdate
        businessObject.Save(dto2); // Calls Session.SaveOrUpdate

        dto1Oid = dto1.Oid ?? Guid.Empty;
        dto2Oid = dto2.Oid ?? Guid.Empty;
    }, batchSize); // Calls Session.SetBatchSize(batchSize); before executing content above, sets it back to default after commit

    // Act
    businessObject.Transact(() =>
    {
        var dto1 = businessObject.LoadObject(dto1Oid);
        var dto2 = businessObject.LoadObject(dto2Oid);

        // Changing data to generate Update requests (should be sent in batches)
        dto1.ArchivingDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        dto2.ArchivingDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        businessObject.Save(dto1);
        businessObject.Save(dto2);
    }, batchSize); // Calls Session.SetBatchSize(batchSize); before executing content above, sets it back to default after commit

    // Assert
    //<Check DB Requests on NHibernate Profiler> // On NHProfiler, the inserts are sent in a single request as seen in "Insert request"
}
```

Insert request (batch correctly sent):

```
INSERT INTO DtoType
            (... Fields)
VALUES      (... Values)

--//////////////////////////////////////////////////

INSERT INTO DtoType
            (... Fields)
VALUES      (... Values)
```

Update Request 1 (first update, should be in batch with request 2 below):

```
UPDATE DtoType
SET    ArchivingDate = '<updated date>'
WHERE  Id = '<dto1 id>'
```

Update request 2 (second update, should be in batch with request 1 above):

```
UPDATE DtoType
SET    ArchivingDate = '<updated date>'
WHERE  Id = '<dto2 id>'
```

My goal is to send only 1 request for both updates, like in the insert request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used NHibernate v4 and the data structure `DtoType` uses versioning. Batch updating versioned structures isn't supported in NH v4.The support was added in v5 ([link here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3771))
Using v5 and adding the nhibernate setting `adonet.batch_versioned_data=true` solved my issue. I can now send batch update requests to the DB.